# Selecting rows with the nearest date using SQL

Tags: sql-server, date, exists

I have a SQL  statement.

```
SELECT 
    ID, LOCATION, CODE,MAX(DATE),FLAG 
FROM 
    TABLE1 
WHERE 
     DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-11-2012') 
     AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #TEMP_CODE WHERE TABLE1.CODE = #TEMP_CODE.CODE) 
     AND ID IN (14, 279)
GROUP BY 
     ID, LOCATION, CODE
```

I need rows with the nearest date to the 11-11-2012, but the table returns all the values.  What am I doing wrong. Thanks

```
ID     LOCATION              CODE            DATE              FLAG
-------------------------------------------------------------------
14  CAR STREET,UDUPI         234      2012-08-08 00:00:00.000   0
14  CAR STREET,UDUPI         234      2012-08-10 00:00:00.000   1
14  CAR STREET,UDUPI         234      2012-08-14 00:00:00.000   0
279 MADHUGIRI                234      2012-08-08 00:00:00.000   1
279 MADHUGIRI                234      2012-08-11 00:00:00.000   0
```

I want to show only the rows with dates less than or equal to the given date. The required result is

```
ID     LOCATION              CODE            DATE              FLAG
-------------------------------------------------------------------
14  CAR STREET,UDUPI         234      2012-08-10 00:00:00.000   1
279 MADHUGIRI                234      2012-08-11 00:00:00.000   0
```

Comment: As a start, why do you use `'11-11-2012'` as your date format? Try `'20121111'`. Also why is the first row August 10 and not August 14?

Comment: @ Aaron Bertrand I'm getting this as a user input. I even tried with the 20121111 format but no luck returns all the five columns

Comment: You know you can control user input right, instead of just passing any old string the user enters on to SQL Server? Why aren't you passing a properly typed date or datetime parameter?

Comment: all records in your table are <= 11-11-2012

Comment: You could set a LIMIT.  Also it looks like all your rows are being returned becuase the WHERE is true

Comment: @AdRock `LIMIT` does not exist in SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, I to see that my where condition returns true for all the five cases but is there an option to take the nearest dates alone

Comment: So can you explain why '2012-08-10' is "nearer" than '2012-08-14' for ID = 14?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the max date for each ID, and then join that to your table:

```
SELECT 
    ID, LOCATION, CODE, DATE, FLAG 
FROM 
    TABLE1 
JOIN (
    SELECT ID AS SubID, MAX(DATE) AS SubDATE 
    FROM TABLE1 
    WHERE DATE < '11/11/2012'
        AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #TEMP_CODE WHERE TABLE1.CODE = #TEMP_CODE.CODE) 
        AND ID IN (14, 279)
    GROUP BY ID
    ) AS SUB ON ID = SubID AND DATE = SubDATE
```

Answer (score 3):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT ID, Location, Code, Date, Flag, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY ID, Location, Code ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
  FROM dbo.TABLE1 AS t1
  WHERE [Date] <= '20121111'
  AND ID IN (14, 279) -- sorry, missed this
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TEMP_CODE WHERE CODE = t1.CODE)
)
SELECT ID, Location, Code, Date, Flag
FROM x WHERE rn = 1;
```

This yields:

```
ID  LOCATION         CODE [Date]     FLAG
--- ---------------- ---- ---------- ----
14  CAR STREET,UDUPI 234  2012-08-14 0
279 MADHUGIRI        234  2012-08-11 0
```

This disagrees with your required results, but I think those are wrong and I think you should check them.

Comment: The required result should be rows less than 20121111 and the one's nearest to 20121111

Comment: @Prince And isn't 20120814 nearer to 2012111 than 20120810? Or can you explain in a different way why you want the row with 20120810 instead of the row with 20120814? I can only ask this question in so many ways - this is 3 or 4 times now. Please EXPLAIN BETTER.

Answer (score -2):

add a Order BY DATE LIMIT 0,2

With the order by you will make the date order by the closest to your condition in where and with the limit will return only the top 2 values!

```
SET ROWCOUNT 2  
SELECT 
    ID, LOCATION, CODE,MAX(DATE),FLAG 
FROM 
    TABLE1 
WHERE 
     DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'11-11-2012') 
     AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #TEMP_CODE WHERE TABLE1.CODE = #TEMP_CODE.CODE) 
     AND ID IN (14, 279)
GROUP BY 
     ID, LOCATION, CODE
ORDER BY DATE
```

Comment: That is exactly what i was thinking

Comment: `LIMIT` doesn't exist in SQL Server (nor any ANSI/ISO SQL standard)

Comment: i didn't saw it was sql server so this way only change limit for SET ROWCOUNT 2. and the hard-coding the ID is his sql query look it. I just added the order by.

Comment: This still doesn't work. You also need to group by FLAG (in which case you might not get the right results at all), or you could perform MIN/MAX on it, but then you could get the wrong FLAG for a particular row. If I GROUP BY Flag, I get two rows for ID 14, and no rows for ID 279. If I MAX() flag I have to convert to tinyint and I get a flag of 1 instead of the expected 0.